# Typescript and lazy imports

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular app with custom webpack where I want to lazy-load svg files.

In custom webpack config I have a loader for SVG files:

```
{
   test: /\.svg$/,
   use: [{loader: 'raw-loader'}]
}
```

I also defined a module for tsconfig:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
   const content: string;
   export default content;
}
```

It works fine when I import svg files statically (e.g. `import icon from 'src/icons/arrow.svg';`), but doesn't when I do this:

```
// types don't resolve, import() returns typeof import("*.svg") instead of string
import('src/icons/arrow-up.svg').then((icon: string) => { })
```

I've tried to search for declaring types for lazy imports with no avail. How to define my own types for lazy imports?

Comment: What do you mean saying "types don't resolve"? Is there a type error? Or is type of `icon` just not inferred automatically and you have to manually write `: string`?

Comment: `import('src/icons/arrow.svg')` returns `Promise<typeof import("*.svg")>` instead of `Promise<string>`.

When I do `import icon from 'src/icons/arrow.svg';), `, however, the icon will have the type `string`, as it should.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the content will be in default prop of the import.

```
import('src/icons/arrow-up.svg').then((icon) => {
   // icon.default is the svg content
})
```